# Why does it look lighter?

Tags: light

Im working on an anvil, following this tutorial all the way around without noticing. 
But now it comes to the texture part and Im totally freak out when it turns out that my anvil is so much lighter than it needs to be, and it affects all the texture thing, you know.

Anyone know why and how to correct?

This is my anvil.

[image]

And this is how it should be.

[image]

Comment: Due to added material slot